# how to use MNIST datast on linux using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

I'm new  in machine learning and I am following tensorflow's tutorial to create some simple Neural Networks which learn the MNIST data.

i wanna run a code that do the recognition hand writing digits using the MNIST data but i don't know how to run it ... should i dowload the data on my machine and extracted and put it on a file and then set the path on the code or did tensorflow contain the data ...but when i do import input_data i get 
No module named 'input_data' also when i do 
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data ==> No module named 'tensorflow.examples' 
ps:when i do import tensorflow as tf i get no erreur so it's fine with tensorflow i think

could u help me plz for example i wanna run the code below what should i do 
 https://github.com/hwalsuklee/tensorflow-mnist-cnn

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot import *tensorflow.examples* I'm guessing something went wrong with the installation. Try reinstalling tensorflow with the latest version. 
You don't need to download the data on your own, tensorflow will put it in the path you provide. But first, try these steps:

I'm currently using tf 1.2.0 and I'm not getting that error.

If you want to know which version you have installed:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

After everything is installed try:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
input_data.read_data_sets("./data/", one_hot=True)
```

That should copy the data to a "data" folder inside your working folder (the "data" folder will be created and all the files will be available there).

If the above lines of code run with no errors, you should be able to run the example.